# PHP-Memcache: How to Store Object of Memcache Connection

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I have just started digging in using Memcached Server in my PHP application and I am caching language string for my multi-lingual app. In my environment I already have PHP Version 5.6.14, PHP-Memcache extension version 3.0.8, Memcached Server v1.4.4-14-g9c660c0 listening on port 11211. I am using Xampp. Everything runs in Windows 10 machine.

But I have question on how do I store the connection object of the Memcached Server using PHP? At the moment I am using `$GLOBALS` but does not seems to work right as it always create new connection while I am trying to use old connection if it exists. Below is what I have (part of my class) based on what I found somewhere on Internet.

```
class CacheMemcache {
    function __construct($name = false, $lifetime = 600){
        if( ! class_exists("Memcache") ){ //Check if Memcache is installed
            exit("PHP Memcache extension does not exists! You need to install it first.");
        }
        // every time this class is initialized, isset return FALSE
        if (isset($GLOBALS["memcache"])) { //Check if already connected to memcached
            $this->memcache = $GLOBALS["memcache"];
        }
        // every time this class is initialized, it always go to the else below
        else{ //No, make new connection
            $this->memcache = new Memcache();
            $this->memcache->connect($this->host, $this->port);
            $GLOBALS["memcache"] = $this->memcache;
        }
    }
}
```

So how do I store the connection of Memcached using PHP? Some guidance are appreciated. Not necessarily using `$GLOBALS` only but other methods are welcome.

**NOTE:**

1. I am aware that there is newer extension called PHP-Memcached extension but my current OS is Windows and I could not find anywhere that I can install PHP-Memcached extension in Windows environment. But the migration is to be considered in the future. Just to have the framework done first.
2. I am also realized that PHP-Memcache has persistent connection `Memcache::pconnect` but not sure how to use it. Based on [official doc](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.pconnect.php) it is similar to `Memcache::connect` but the connection is persistent. However I will still end up of having the question above.

Comment: Can't help you with how to get it done but, if you're trying to persist the connect, `$GLOBALS` can't help you. The values in there don't persist from one connection to the next.

Comment: @Terminus thanks for the comment and yes i am trying to make the connection object persist. Just don't want to do connect every time.